# What is causing this test output (rake test)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rake, minitest

I've been playing around with getting some tests set up on my project and am looking at using the minitest-reporters gem to "pretty up" my output, but no matter what I do, I get this output that seems like it is fighting with something else and messes up the output.

You can see an image here (not enough rep to post myself) - [screen capture](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/content_link/lIqkzkdazA7Vp4qb9DYtYLEtza6t1PFzuWDyEasZ9KusTXEFWjI1dd4cuT8kZWqx/file)

I've spent a few hours digging around online and digging through my gems/test setup and can't seem to identify the source.  I was hoping somebody could help me identify what would cause the output and figure out how to prevent it.

I WANT the progress bar output from minitest-reporters....I'm trying to get rid of the output that includes:

```
--------------------------
Sampletest:  test_case_two
--------------------------
```

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. The reason you were not allowed to include the screenshot is because screenshots generally mean you're posting an _image of the problem_ instead of [including the problem in your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)). Generally speaking, if you're having a problem, an answerer should be able to `Ctrl` + `F` and search for the problem in your question. If you fail that smoke test, something is wrong with your question. Please edit with the issues you're having!

Answer (score 0):

After I posted this, I began digging through my Gemfile and found that the issue is caused because I've included `rails_stdout_logging` since I'm deploying to Heroku.

There are some different solutions to the issue [here](https://github.com/heroku/rails_stdout_logging/issues/6) as well.